# Optional route parameters in Backbone.js? (again)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascriptmvc, backbone-routing

I'm trying to set up routing in Backbone 0.9.10. I'd like to match routes of the following kind:

```
/england/
/england/birmingham
/france
/france/paris
...
```

etc. This is what I have in my router at the moment:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "index",
    "(/:country)": "index",
    "(/:country)(/:city)": "index"
  },
  index: function(country, city) { 
      console.log('index', country, city);
  }
});
var StateApp = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

I have two problems:

1. The 'index' function isn't firing at all at the moment, whatever URL I go to = `/`, `/england` or anything else.
2. I'm also not clear if the optional parameters will work the way I have set them up - is it OK to have two optional parameters in a row like this? I don't know how many countries I need to support yet, so I do want the `country` parameter to be a parameter, rather than specifying individual countries.

I'd much rather use proper URL routing than regex parsing if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want, as in your example, to route all urls (including the root) to one method, your only need to define one route:

```
routes: {
  "(:country)(/:city)": "index"
}
```

Because both parameters are optional, this will match:

- "" (Empty string)
- "england"
- "england/london"

If you want only the routes in format of `england` and `england/london` but not the root page `/`, declare a separate empty route, and make the `:country` part non-optional:

```
routes: {
  "" : "home",
  ":country(/:city)": "index"
}
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much. I just didn't need the initial slash.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a single route and have flexibility to change what you want the urls to look like. you could also consider

```
routes: {
 "(/country/:country)(/city/:city)": "index"
}
```

---

matching

```
"" (Empty string)
"country/england"
"country/england/city/london"
```